# How to update a laravel project in aws Elastic beanstalk, while keeping the same storage

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to update my Laravel project in aws beanstalk, but the problem is the storage in tha aws elastic beanstalk is now different , and i want to keep it, i dont know how , cuz my Project contains a storage folder, but it's empty, and if i update it , i'll loose all the files
how can i update the code, but keep the storage ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application should be designed to be **stateless**. The reason is that your EB instances always run in an [Auto Scaling group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/AutoScalingGroup.html).

This means that they can be terminated and **replaced at any time**, without your knowledge or involvement. There are **many scenarios** under which that may happen. Examples are, Availability Zone re-balance, migration to new physical hardware, scaling in and out activities, or instance health degradation.

Subsequently, you are always at risk loosing your storage, whether you like it or not.

Therefore you application should be designed as stateless, which means that it **does not store any data** on the instance. This is achieved usually by storing the data in an external storage such as EFS:

- [How can I mount an Amazon EFS volume to an instance in my Elastic Beanstalk environment?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-mount-efs-volumes/)

But if you still want to **keep your design**, you can always use `.ebextentions` scripts to help you replace the storage folder. Specifically, in [Commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands) you would make a copy of your storage folder to a safe location at the start of the new deployment. Then in [Container commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands) you would copy the files back to your new application folder, just before the new deployment completes.

Comment: thank you so much , that was helpful , I'm thinking of using S3 instead of EFS, is that ok ? or EFS is better for web apps ?