# storage:link not working properly while deploying laravel application to elastic beanstalk via codecommit

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, laravel-8, aws-codecommit

I am using Elastic Beanstalk environment to host my Laravel application.

And I'm using CodeCommit as codesource when I'm deploying with EB CLI.

Lastly, I'm using an init.config file inside .ebextensions folder to automatically run some commands for my EC2 instances.

```
//init.config inside .ebextensions
container_commands:
    01storagelink:
        command: "php artisan storage:link"
```

This command IS working when I make deployment BUT it is linking the public/storage to an unexpected path (for me) as shown in the picture:

[image]

Whereas it should be like this:

[image]

How can I resolve the issue? (I'm going to keep the research in the meantime)

Answer (score 0):

I have found out why it is creating the symbolic link under staging directory:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands

Shame I haven't read related parts of the documentation but I was in kind of hurry at that time.

Instead of finding a solution for this, I have found out that I need to set up external storage:

[How to update a laravel project in aws Elastic beanstalk, while keeping the same storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163778/how-to-update-a-laravel-project-in-aws-elastic-beanstalk-while-keeping-the-same)

So, I set up an S3 bucket and no need for storage:link for now.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS Elastic Beanstalk (EB) Deployment workflow comprises multiple [stages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html#platforms-linux-extend.workflow), each with distinct functionalities.

As you correctly pointed out, the command file `/ebextensions` operates within the `/var/app/staging` workspace. Consequently, it is advisable to run all application-related commands during the post-deploy stage, which is specifically designed for this purpose.

Keywords:
`.platform/hooks/postdeploy`